# Phabricator: Setup issue

Tags: phabricator

I am having a issue in setting up phabricator. I getting an the following error when I navigate to the site URL -"Bad getter Call: getTranslation". I am not able to ascertain if the cause of the issue with the phabricator code or APC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your are missing some requirements.

If you are not sure of what you are doing, I strongly advise going for an installer such as the Bitnami one, I've been using their stacks for a while and my company' Phabricator is installed that way.

see https://bitnami.com/stack/phabricator